# What is the best way to include my assets files in Reacj Js App Such as CSS, JQuery, JS, SVG, ICONS

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, svg

I am creating a react js app and am stuck on how to import my asset folders, i created an *app* folder and create a sub folder called *asset* , so i want to import the component such as bootstrap, js, css, fonts, svg, JQuery. I created all the JS, and also customized the bootstrap, also created some SVG and some font icons, but whenever i used the import function, i it always complain error, also i tried linking the css using general inline css import inside the App.css component, still brings error.

Kindly help

Comment: you should be experienced with bundlers like webpack, if you are not, then use [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) which gives you everything out-of-the-box

Comment: What errors are you seeing? We're going to need a lot more detail than you've currently provided.

Comment: @hitmands i created the app with creat-react-app but i don't know how to include it, i can include it in the indxex.html file and it works normally like but there are some assets that will not be necessary in some pages which if i should include it in the index.html file it will be on all page

Comment: @robert when i tried linking the assets using `import 'assets/css/bootstarp.css` it tells me the error that font files were missing and also in the console it give some error notice that file missing